# Android Bottom Sheet is coming from the bottom of the CoordinatorLayout, not the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have my Layout XML that looks roughly like below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/svDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llSomeDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

From what I can tell, the bottomSheetContent should come from the bottom of the screen, not the bottom of the view.  The llSomeDetails has a good bit of content so it normally goes off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/svDetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSomeDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
 <!-- include your bottom sheet here -->
 <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Keep in mind that a bottom sheet must be created in a separate layout file and then imported to your main activity's layout